# input checkbox marked out of the box vuejs components

Tags: html, css, vue.js

good day, I have a small problem, when I click on the areas I marked on the picture, the checkbox on the left is marked. What is the reason for this?
[image]

```
<div class="form-check my-5">
<input
  class="form-check-input border-2 border-rectangle"
  type="checkbox"
  :required="required"
  id="checkbox"
  v-model="value"
  @change="$emit('select', value)"
/>
<label v-if="label" class="form-check-label text-gray-800" for="checkbox"> {{ label }}</label>
```

Comment: That's how they should work if you have an `input` element with an ID and a label with corresponding `for` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the **for** attribute in the label tag.
you can just remove it if you don't need this behavior

Answer (score -2):

Use span tag instead of div . The div has block property so it's take block area .

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, what should I use instead of what?

Comment: The answers don't seem relevant to the question.